# What is an optimal way to transfer 300 GB of data from one laptop to another, and back?

Tags: ubuntu, file-transfer

I need to perform an operating system reinstall on my **Ubuntu 14.04** machine. I have valuable data of size **300 GB** that I would like to temporarily back up to another laptop (running **Windows7**), and copy it back after reinstalling the OS on my main laptop.

Details:

- The data in question sits on an NTFS partition
- the 2 laptops are connected to the same Wireless access point
- no cable connection between the 2 laptops
- no USB flash storage device with a large capacity (only 2 GB)

Comment: Have you looked this question ?http://askubuntu.com/questions/107208/how-to-setup-a-lan-between-ubuntu-and-windows

Answer (score 1):

You can simply google the endless possibilities you have. You can just share folders and access them via WiFi or even better, via LAN.

Comment: Definitely not LAN, cause I do not have an Ethernet cable.

Comment: Then WiFi, whats the point? If you have no hardware for this purpose, what do you want to hear? That you can beam the data using your finger? So take what you got, and this seems to be either WiFi or USB.

Comment: It is highly recommended to use Ethernet cable instead of WLAN, since it will provide stable connection between the both computer. As for 300GB, you do not want the connection to break down at the last MB. Ethernet cable is cheap to have.

Comment: In a normal environment that should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , I would get an external hard drive and make a backup of the data. If you have no choice occurs to me you can do one of two things :

1 - You can create multiple partitions on your hard drive with gparted and create one for data about 320GB and save your data there . Then reinstall ubuntu manually specifying partitions. Be very careful not to delete or overwrite 320GB partition containing your data.

2 - Create a network drive in ubuntu . Write to disk all your data. And then in Windows 7 , connect to that network drive and copy the data on the laptop.

Comment: I haven't worked with Linux partitions, so I won't go that route.    The thing is, the partition holding my data is an NTFS one and I want to format it to a ext4 linux file system.